# iterm2 repeating "command not fund: Enable/close" constantly

Tags: terminal, zsh, iterm2, zshrc

I am learning coding for about two months, and I was trying to install Homebrew, oh my zsh and Powerlevel10k yesterday. I got some problems, so I google it for solutions, and I end up to entered:

**source ~/.zshrc**

Since then my terminal is broken by my careless...

Like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6myI.png

```
ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"# Enable Powerlevel10k instant prompt. Should stay 
close to the top of ~/.zshrc.
POWERLEVEL9K_DISABLE_CONFIGURATION_WIZARD=true

# Initialization code that may require console input (password prompts, [y/n]
# confirmations, etc.) must go above this block; everything else may go below.
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi

# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:${PATH}

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in $ZSH/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment one of the following lines to change the auto-update behavior
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode disabled  # disable automatic updates
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode auto      # update automatically without asking
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode reminder  # just remind me to update when it's time

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# zstyle ':omz:update' frequency 13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# You can also set it to another string to have that shown instead of the default red dots.
# e.g. COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="%F{yellow}waiting...%f"
# Caution: this setting can cause issues with multiline prompts in zsh < 5.7.1 (see #5765)
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(
    git
    zsh-autosuggestions
)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
source ~/.zshrc
setopt no_nomatch

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh

# Syntax hightlight
plugins=( [plugins...] zsh-syntax-highlighting)
```

I am Macanese, so if my English is too confusing, I am so sorry, and if my question is too silly, I am sorry too...

I really want to fix this, so I can use my vscode's terminal learn how to use git.

Thank you for bearing with me!

Comment: Can you paste a part of your `.zshrc` in the question itself, especially the part where it says "Enable" or "close"?

Comment: I can't share pictures, buz my level is not enough, but I did share the picture by link. I will paste the code of .zshrc in the question! Thank you for your time!

Comment: Ah, there we go! There *should* be a space (or newline) before the hash sign on the `# Enable` line, and there *should not* be a newline before the `close`.

Comment: Oh! thank you very much! I am too careless, but I have learned! Your profile is amazing! you are my hero!

Comment: Is the file you have posted here your .zshrc? I hope it isn't, because halfway down this file, there is a `source ~/.zshrc`, which means that you would source the file recorsively.

Comment: That is my .zshrc. Sorry I am not quite understand, So should I do something to make it  right?

Comment: I just deleted it, and I can save my powerlever10k's config now! But what is the principle behind it, can you tell me? If it doesn't bothers you. Thank you!